# Can't match this regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I need to apply a regexp for replacing a block of a string.

this is my code:

```
var style = "translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(3590px, 490px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1)";

style = style.replace(/translate3d\(.+\)/,"asdf");
```

I need to replace that part: `"translate3d(3590px, 490px, 0px)"`
but it doesn't work because it replaces until the last ")" so it will be: `"translate(-50%, -50%) asdf"`

Answer (score 7):

Use a *non-greedy* regular expression:

```
style = style.replace(/translate3d\(.+?\)/,"asdf");
```

Putting `?` after `+` makes it uses the shortest match instead of the longest.

Answer (score 3):

`.` matches all characters.  Force it to skip the closing parentheses:

```
style = style.replace(/translate3d\([^)]+\)/,"asdf");
```

Trying it out:

```
> var style = "translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(3590px, 490px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1)";
> style = style.replace(/translate3d\([^)]+\)/,"asdf");
'translate(-50%, -50%) asdf rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

*it replaces untils the last ")"* because the "+" quantifier is greedy by default. You can change this by placing a "?" just after it.

The correct regex is then:`translate3d\(.+?\)`.

Comment: I think you start typing the answer before he edited the question, because he did escape the parentheses.

Comment: Didn't _you_ escape his parentheses? (sorry if I am wrong reading the revisions page, I am quite new to SO) Anyway, you are correct, I started typing before your editing his question.

Comment: No, I just fixed formatting. I would never modify the code in the question in any significant way. The edit history doesn't show that change, which means it was made within a minute or two of creating the question.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. Thanks. I will remove this part of my answer, then.